# RDP is enabled but doesn't show up in netstat

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I've enabled RDP on a laptop, but I can't connect to it. Pinging the laptop works. `nmap` shows ports open, but not RDP. `netstat` on the laptop shows nothing listening on 3389. I've also tried rebooting.

Additional info:

Start > Computer > Properties > Remote Settings > Remote:

[image: Remote Settings]

Relevant registry settings:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections = 0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd\Tds\tcp\PortNumber = 3389
```

Nmap scan:

```
$ nmap xxx.xx.xx.xxx

Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2013-06-05 12:57 MDT
Interesting ports on xxx.xx.xx.xxx:
Not shown: 1675 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
135/tcp open     msrpc
137/tcp filtered netbios-ns
138/tcp filtered netbios-dgm
139/tcp open     netbios-ssn
445/tcp open     microsoft-ds

$ ping xxx.xx.xx.xxx
PING xxx.xx.xx.xxx (xxx.xx.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.35 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=3.41 ms
64 bytes from xxx.xx.xx.xxx: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=4.02 ms

--- xxx.xx.xx.xxx ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.412/4.263/5.351/0.809 ms
```

Comment: you've rebooted I assume?

Comment: Yep, I've tried rebooting.

Comment: Have you checked to see if Windows firewall is blocking it?

Comment: Check to see if the service is running. Start---Run---Services.msc

Comment: @Scandalist That worked. Turns out 'Remote Desktop Services' was disabled. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

RDP relies heavily on the Windows Firewall Service whether it is enabled or not.  Allowing the RDP service via manual registry settings is not always possible.  First enable your Windows firewall prior to turning Remote Desktop Connections off and on again.  Apply the change, then try and connect.  Always connect using the IP address of your remote computer unless you are in a corporate or private LAN environment with fully working DNS.  If it works you can then disable Windows firewall if it was disabled before.  I have noticed that if the firewall service is disabled when you try to use the GUI to enable RDP, it will not allow it to be enabled even if you manually configure the registry and start the relevant services.
Good luck!

This might help you too.

http://www.sysprobs.com/connect-remote-desktop-windows-7-fix